# Print dataframe with int and nan to csv

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'int':1, 'float':1.1, 'str':'aaa'}, {'int':None, 'float':None, 'str':None}])

df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

We want to dump the df out to a csv like below (using '#|#' as field delimiter), keeping int as int:

```
int#|#float#|#str
1#|#1.1#|#aaa
#|##|#
```

How do I achieve that?

The workaround below works, but my DataFrame is huge and I wonder if there's a better / more efficient way:

```
df['int'] = df['int'].apply(lambda x: ('%.0f' % x) if x != '' else x)
np.savetxt('test.txt', df[['int', 'float', 'str']].values, fmt='%s', delimiter='#|#', newline="\n")
```

Comment: _using '#|#' as field delimiter_ Why?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding you cannot dump a dataframe to a cab with a # delimintor. Cab automatically apply , as the delimintor. You can convert your dataframe to a CSV file use the to_csv method of the pandas dataframe class

Comment: '#|#' as delimiter works with numpy. I verified that. My question is how to dump int as int instead of 1.1

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to force the column types to obj. It is only required for the `int` column, but it must be done before pandas writes a NaN value into an integer column. When it happens, the column is converted to float.

So you could do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'int':1, 'float':1.1, 'str':'aaa'}, {'int':None, 'float':None, 'str':None}], dtype=object)

df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

You would get:

```
  float int  str
0   1.1   1  aaa
1
```

Comment: Yes, the above works for printing the df, but then savetxt doesn't work. I have to use %s in numpy.savetxt fmt param. Using %.f doesn't work because of the ''. My goal is to dump it to txt